# Calculating time of simulation in Java

Tags: java, android, timer, game-physics, mathematical-optimization

I am doing a project on a bird killing game. Every thing working fine but i want that my bird cross the screen in **35 seconds** for any given mobile screen. And after every **20 seconds** its time reduced to 31. What will be the mathematical formula(for speed) to cross the screen in 35 seconds? Currently am updating x-axis value in **update** method and creating rectangle for the bird-sprites.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Random;
public class Birds extends GameObject implements View.OnTouchListener{
private Bitmap spritesheet;
private Rect rect;
public boolean firstTym = true;
private Animation animation = new Animation();
private String tag = "";
private int  y,touchX,touchY;
public int x=0;
private long startTime;

public Birds(String tag)
{
    this.tag = tag;
    spritesheet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Constants.res, R.drawable.bird_sprites);
    dy = 0;
    if(Constants.Width > 1300) {
        width = 120;
        height = 140;

    }
    else {

        width = 80;
        height = 72;
    }
    Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[5];


    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++)
    {
        image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height);
    }

    animation.setFrames(image);
    animation.setDelay(10);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
public void update()
{
    if(!firstTym) {
// here i am updating speed of bird in x-axis.
//i want bird to cross the screen in 35 seconds
        x += Constants.speed;
        Log.e("speed = ","" + Constants.speed);
    }
    else
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        r.nextInt(Constants.Width);
    }

    if(x > GamePanel.WIDTH){
        Constants.missed ++;
        x = 0;
    }
    if(y > GamePanel.HEIGHT)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Random r = new Random();
    if (x == 0 || firstTym) {
        y = r.nextInt(GamePanel.HEIGHT - 150);

        Constants.RAND = r.nextInt(1);
        firstTym = false;
    }
    animation.update();

    y += Constants.RAND;
    rect = new Rect(x, y, x + 80, 72 + y);
    setRect(rect);
    setTag(tag);
    canvas.drawBitmap(animation.getImage(), null, rect, null);
    if (x < 0) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(animation.getImage(), null, rect, null);
    }
}
public int getX()
{
    return x;
}
public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    touchX = (int)event.getX();
    touchY = (int)event.getY();
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What will be the mathematical formula to calculate the crossing time? this statement is a lil ambiguous. coz you are saying that you want to accelerate your bird to cross screen in 35 seconds then for which time you want to calculate?

Comment: i guess you want to calculate the speed of you bird. that at what speed it should move to cross any sized screen in 35 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed is distance over time. If I move 10 meters in 2 seconds then I am moving at 10 divide by 2 meters per second which is 5 meters per second. We can write it as `s = D / t` where `s` is speed, `D` is distance, and `t` is time. With that we can arrange it so that we can define any of the components in terms of the other two.

thus we get

```
s = D / t; // get the speed in term of distance and time
t = D / s; // get the time in term of distance and speed
D = t * s; // get the distance in term of time and speed
```

You have the distance D in pixels (ie the width) and the time, in seconds. You will need to get the system clock time `startTime` when you start the bird flying, the current time `timeNow`. You will need the `x` and `y` position where the bird starts, and the x and y position `xEnd`,`yEnd`of where the bird will be in the time, and the time you want it to take `time`

At the start you need to set up the variables you need. I Don't do java (yuck) so can not remember the class to get system time. Just look it up in the reference docs.

```
// set up
time = 35; // how long to cross the screen
x = 0; // start pos
y = 100; // 
xEnd = screenWidth;  // end pos
yEnd = 100;
startTime = ?.now() // ? is whatever class you get the system time from
```

With all that to get the position of the bird.

```
// each frame get the time in seconds
timeNow = ?;
if( timeNow - startTime < time) { // make sure time is not over
    currentX = x + ((xEnd - x) / time) * (timeNow - startTime))
    currentY = y + ((yEnd - y) / time) * (timeNow - startTime))
}else{
   // All done
}
```

You know its all over when `timeNow - startTime  > time`

If the time is in millisecond or smaller you will need to convert it to seconds by dividing. Ie for milliseconds `time = timeInMillisecond / 1000;`